# Barchart of Google -- trying to make it horizontal, but it remains vertical

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I'm using Column charts https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart of Google and it works fine. However, for some data I need  horizontal charts. Bar char is suggested https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart and I'm using it but this

```
      bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
```

Doesn't work, namely, a chart is still vertical. Everything else is working fine.

What can be an issue? And what does "// Required for Material Bar Charts." mean?

Comment: @Dinesh, https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/ is empty. What should I use to make it horizontal?

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/xg4a0ud8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two "versions" of google charts, Classic and Material...

**Classic**

loaded with --> `packages: ['corechart']`

Column Chart --> `google.visualization.ColumnChart`

Bar Chart --> `google.visualization.BarChart`

---

**Material**

loaded with --> `packages: ['bar']`

Both use the same chart --> `google.charts.Bar`

the chart option `bars` determines which direction the chart is displayed...

Column Chart --> `bars: 'vertical'`

Bar Chart --> `bars: 'horizontal'`